# О диапазоне воприятия сказанного

Tags: прямая-речь

Человеческий мозг, воспринимает только малую часть из вкусового, звукового, видимого спектров. Мы не слышим ультразвук, не видим в ультрафиолете и так далее. Речь — язык, такой же орган человека. Наша речь — откалиброванные гармонические  звуковые колебания. Это так? На сколько процентов мы понимаем что говорим, читаем и пишем? Каков истинный (ультра — инфра) диапазон речи?

Answer (score 1):

Свою речь мы понимаем на 100%, но часть этого понимания происходит на невербальном уровне. Чужую речь мы можем как не понимать вовсе (0%), так и понимать абсолютно (100%), но чаще всего понимаем лишь определенную часть. По опыту перевода текстов с иностранных языков, для четкого и однозначного перевода достаточно знать 30-50% ключевых слов. А чтобы на экзамене пересказать полуторачасовую лекцию, студенту, как правило, хватает 10 минут (11%).

Comment: Каков процент, по вашему невербального, понимания ? И что скрывается за кадром сознания?

Comment: @Бывалый, процент невербального понимания зависит от того, о чём человек говорит, и уровня развития его понятийного аппарата. В выводе хорошей научной работы невербального уровня почти нет, а в живой непосредственной речи зачастую слов нет, одни эмоции.

Answer (score 0):

Формально вопрос некорректный. Нет линейки или термометра, которыми можно было бы померить физическую информативности речи. Понимания - тем более. Вот вы уверны, предположим, что поняли то, что я сейчас прочитали? А на сколько процентов?

А если говорить вообще в терминах, далеких от математической теории информации... 
Тут скорее надо говорить о распознавании речи, письменной или устной... Это распознавание в общем-то действительно близко в стопроцентному (если исключить случайные помехи). Но только в том случае, если принимающий может свести сигнал к известным ему ранее терминам.

Answer (score 0):

Оператор-наблюдатель  диктует через микрофон нужную для передачи  фразу, которая  детектируется в низкочастотные электрические сигналы. Эти сигналы модулируются (накладываются) на СВЧ-  или КВЧ-  направленное излучение.  Направленное  излучение взаимодействует с головным мозгом человека (на которого направлено это излучение), его внутренним ухом, акустическими и другими нервами. При интенсивности сигнала ниже уровня восприятия,  сообщение оператора  поступает в подсознание человека, который принимает сообщение, переданное  оператором, за свои собственные мысли.  Аналогичным образом в обратном порядке могут быть прочитаны мысли подопытного пациента. Таким же образом может быть передана звуковая речь оператора. Поэтому человек слышит в голове голоса, любую музыку, все, что ему передает оператор. Человек, не знакомый с современными техническими возможностями, начинает считать себя больным, идет к психиатру, и этим подписывает себе приговор.